# Recursively look through a whole directory tree, modify filenames of all files and move the tree excluding hidden . files

Tags: python, python-2.7, shutil

Hi Im really struggling trying to move some files around.

What I want to do is look through a directory find all files that are .jpg and do not start with '.'. I want to modify the filenames of all the jpg's and move them into another directory while keeping them in their sub directories. Some jpg's are in the the root directory and not in a sub. All the files need to be removed from the original place after moving except hidden .files

So far I have tried lots of things, one was to:

```
xmpDir = '/Users/richard/Desktop/_xmpDir' 
xmpAdded = '/Users/richard/Desktop/_xmpAdded'

os.chdir(xmpDir)
cwd = os.getcwd()
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(cwd):
    print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)
    for sub in subdirList:
        print(sub)
    for fname in fileList:
        if not fname.startswith('.'):
            print(fname)

            if not os.path.exists(xmpAdded + '/' + sub  ):                            
                os.makedirs(xmpAdded + '/' + sub  )
            shutil.move(dirName + '/' + fname, xmpAdded + '/' + sub + '/' + fname)
```

All this does is move all the files into the first sub directory it comes across.

I can use os.walk to go through all the directories and make changes to my files but when I go to move them it puts them all in one folder:

```
os.chdir(xmpDir)
cwd = os.getcwd()
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(cwd):
    for fname in fileList:
        if not fname.startswith('.'):
            newFname = removeID(fname)
            print(newFname)
            print(fname)
            shutil.move(dirName + '/' + fname, newPath1 + '/' + dirName + newFname)
```

I would really appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks

Comment: You need to write recursive function to handle this situation.For each of directory check sub directory list if any present then function calls itself using that sub directory as argument.

Comment: Try this in code:  shutil.move(os.path.join(dirName,fname), os.path.join(newPath1,dirName,newFname))